# Return next date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I have a table with 2 columns and I need to calculate the `next_report_date` based on the information of `Frequency` and `Created_date`.

Functional description is: it should always be the upcoming Wednesday that could be today or in the future (I added the days in the table to clarify).

So if the created date is 21-mar and the frequency is "Weekly", the `next_report_date` should be Wednesday 22-mar (after 22-mar the `next_report_date` should change to 29-mar).

If the created date is 24-mar and the frequency is "Bi-weekly", the `next_report_date` should be Wednesday 05-apr (after 5-apr, the `next_report_date` should change to 19-apr).

If the created date is 16-feb and the frequency is "Monthly", the `next_report_date` should be Wednesday 12-apr.

If the created date is 3-jan and the frequency is "Bi-monthly", the `next_report_date` should be Wednesday 19-apr

Result should look like this *(but only first 3 columns. The last 2 columns Next and etc are to help understand what I need to accomplish)*

| Frequency | Created_date | Next_report_date | Next | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Weekly (7 days) | 2023-03-21 | 2023-03-22 | 2023-03-29 |  |
| Bi-weekly (14 days) | 2023-03-21 | 2023-04-05 | 2023-04-19 |  |
| Monthly (28 days) | 2023-02-16 | 2023-04-12 | 2023-05-10 |  |
| Bi-monthly (56 days) | 2023-01-03 | 2023-04-19 | 2023-06-14 |  |

Does anyone know how to calculate this?

I tried writing a SQL statement, but I kept repeating the same line of code which could take years, so I think I might need a cursor. But that's unfortunately way to complex for me now. Need to figure that out slowly

Comment: I've done something similar before, a simple case expression should do the job.

Comment: Are you defining month as 28 days rather than calendar month?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this query :

```
with cte as (
  select *,
  CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Created_date)<=4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as 'coeff'
  From next_report_date
)
select Frequency, Created_date, 
  CASE 
           WHEN Frequency = 'Weekly (7 days)' then DATEADD(DAY , 7*coeff+4-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Created_date),Created_date)
           WHEN Frequency = 'Bi-weekly (14 days)' then DATEADD(DAY , 14+14*coeff+4-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Created_date),Created_date)
           WHEN Frequency = 'Monthly (28 days)' then DATEADD(DAY , 28+28*coeff+4-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Created_date),Created_date)
           WHEN Frequency = 'Bi-monthly (56 days)' then DATEADD(DAY , 56+56*coeff+4-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Created_date),Created_date)
  END
  AS 'next_report_date' 
from cte
```

Explanation:

`DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Created_date)` returns the weekday (starting with 0 for monday, 6 is sunday). Subtract the `Created_date` weekday from 4 and get the remaining days until next Wednesday as a result. Then add them to the `Created_date` date and get next Wednesday's date.

`DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Created_date)<4` to check if the Created_date is before wednesday or not, if it is before then we check on the current interval if not we check next interval

The result is bit different than your expected when it is Monthly or Bi-Monthly :

```
Frequency               Created_date    next_report_date
Weekly (7 days)         2023-03-21      2023-03-22
Weekly (7 days)         2023-03-22      2023-03-22
Weekly (7 days)         2023-03-23      2023-03-29
Bi-weekly (14 days)     2023-03-21      2023-04-05
Monthly (28 days)       2023-02-16      2023-04-12
Bi-monthly (56 days)    2023-01-03      2023-03-01
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/_oSg9T4a)

Comment: This will only show the first next_report_date. For example: if i were to run this query on march 21, the weekly would indeed show the correct date, but if it's the 23th, it should show 29

Comment: Can you check my update

Comment: Watch out, DATEPART WEEKDAY changes depending on your DATEFIRST server settings